# Echo hash in PHP

Tags: php, hash

I have what is probably a very simple question, but seeing as I am a beginner I cant seem to find an answer. I want to print my hash to a website (to confirm that it gets hashed properly). But when i echo it, I dont get anything back. What I am expecting is a hashed string. Here is the code, please help:

```
  <?php

$index = 1;
$data = rand(1,4);
$myhash = hash($index, $data);

?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
    echo "$index <br>";
    echo "$data <br>";
    echo "$myhash <br>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you read about [`hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) arguments?

Comment: What have you tried debugging that code?

Comment: @u_mulder hinted it, you didn't read about `hash` function arguments. Simply head on to www.php.net and type in the function name in the URL, you're a beginner so there's no point downvoting this. Here's the [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) documentation. You need to specify which *algorithm* to use.

Comment: In a nutshell, the $index is wrong. However, depending on what you are going to do with this hash... you may be headed toward using `password_hash()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hash` function needs a hashing algorithm specified as its first argument. You are providing the number 1 which is not a valid algorithm.

Read up on the hash function and choose the appropriate algorithm. For example:

```
$myhash = hash('sha256', $data);
```

Comment: Oh, ok. I had no idea. Honestly - i read the documentation up and down, however I would have never figured that out...

Answer (score 4):

A good practice is to debug your code.

Use this at the start of your page (for development purpose only, not production!):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);


$index = 1;
$data = rand(1,4);
$myhash = hash($index, $data);

?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
    echo "$index <br>";
    echo "$data <br>";
    echo "$myhash <br>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

So you'll get an error like:

```
E_WARNING : type 2 -- hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: 1 -- at line 5
```

It's because, first argument of [hash()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.hash.php) function must be a name of a hash algorithm, like **"md5", "sha256", "haval160,4"**.

So in your case, you should change $index by something like:

```
$index = "sha256";
```

and not a number like you did.

Comment: thank you! was actually looking for something to "force unwrap" the hash as a string (or what ever) to see what happened to it

Answer (score 0):

hash function requires hashing algorithm as 1st argument.

```
string hash(string $algo , string $data [, bool $raw_output = FALSE ])
```

You are not proving a hashing algorithm. Try putting md5, sha256, haval160 etc as hashing algorithm .
check php.net for more info.
[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)